# Trying to return the sum of the area of two objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to return the sum of the area of two objects. Here is the program that's suppose to do that:

```
public class TestSumArea
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
         GeometricObject[] a = {
                 new Circle (2.4),
                 new Rectangle (3, 5)};
    }


    public static double sumArea(GeometricObject[] a)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            sum += a[i].getArea();
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

I keep getting `cannot find symbol - method getArea()` and I don't know why.

Here is the `Circle` program (the `Rectangle` one is basically the same just with height and width).

```
public class Circle extends GeometricObject
{

    public double radius;

    public Circle (double radius) 
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        return radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is `getArea()` an abstract method you are inheriting?

Comment: @3kings no it's not an abstract method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your `GeometricObject` class or interface to implement or declare the `getArea` method, since your array is of type `GeometricObject`.

The child classes (`Circle`, `Rectangle`, and so on) can then `@Override` that method.

The concrete implementation of `getArea` for each `GeometricObject` in your array will be resolved at runtime.

**Example**

```
abstract class GeometricObject {
    /* You can actually draft a default implementation 
       here if you're using an abstract class.
       Otherwise you may want to opt for an interface.
    */
    abstract double getArea(); 
}
class Rectangle extends GeometricObject {
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        // TODO calculations
        return 0; //draft
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I do that by putting this: abstract public void getArea(); in GeometricObject ? @Mena

Comment: @Melanie see my example. The `abstract public void getArea();` idiom will work both if `GeometricObject` is an `abstract` class or an `interface` (although `abstract` and `public` are not needed for an `interface`, they're implicit). If the `GeometricObject` class is concrete, you **need** to implement `getArea` in there too, although you probably don't want it as a concrete class to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You have `GeometricObject[] a` so when you call `a[i].getArea()` the `getArea()` method must be on `GeometricObject` It can be an abstract method, but the signature has to be there.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert GeometricObject from class to an interface
2. Add statement `public double getArea();` to GeometricObject interface
3. change Circle & Rectangle to implement GeometricObject instead of extend.

Comment: Point 1 and 3: not necessarily. You can have it as an `abstract` class too if you're willing to provide default functionality.